# Stuck Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk... after upgrade flutter sdk

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

After upgrading the **Flutter SDK** version, something strange happened to me,
I just executed the `flutter run` command, stopped working at this point

> Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, gone after uninstalling the app and doing 'Flutter clean ' from the terminal. this should do it.